# MySQL 5.7 wont Install On Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mysql

I have tried following several posts and have been searching for several hours for a solution and cant install any version of mysql on Ubuntu 20.04.

I am getting the following errors at present:

```
   Unpacking mysql-community-server (5.7.33-1ubuntu18.04) ...
   Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
   Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.33-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
   Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.33-1ubuntu18.04) ...
   Setting up libmecab2:amd64 (0.996-10build1) ...
   Setting up mysql-community-server (5.7.33-1ubuntu18.04) ...
   update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my                                                                                    .cnf) in auto mode
   my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 - No such                                                                                     file or directory)
   my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
   my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 - No such                                                                                     file or directory)
   my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
   my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 - No such                                                                              file or directory)
   my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
   my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 - No such                                                                                     file or directory)
   my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
   mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or dir                                                                                    ectory)
   mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
   dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
    installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess re                                                                                           turned error exit status 1
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
    mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 5.7.33-1ubuntu18.04); however                                                                                    :
     Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

   dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro                                                                                    r from a previous failure.
                             Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
   Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
   Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
   Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
   Errors were encountered while processing:
    mysql-community-server
    mysql-server
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried everything except how to actually get it installed. Any assist appreciated thanks

Comment: You can't install any version?  How exactly are you trying to install it?

Comment: @Nmath Ive tried following loads of posts. mysql 8 doesnt install either. Which I wouldnt want as my databases are 5.7 databases. 

I tried these commands just, and that spirts out the errors mentioned in the post.
sudo apt install mysql-client=5.7.33-1ubuntu18.04
sudo apt install mysql-server=5.7.33-1ubuntu18.04

I was informed (by a post) that I had to install the client first as above, but I get the errors still.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 will not easily install on Ubuntu 20.04 and, if you do get it installed, future system updates can break it quite easily. This is due to 5.7 requesting specific libraries that have been deprecated for a couple of years. If you *must* use 5.7, there are two options: (1) use a Docker container (2) use an Ubuntu Server 18.04 VM

Comment: Thanks @Matigo. I have decided to completely reinstall back to 18.04. Then make sure I get the snapshot feature in place before attempting again. Thanks. Its not 5.7 It must be something in the upgrade from 18.04 that broke as mysql 8 wont even install. And if it dis my database sql files would most likely fail to install.

Comment: It seems like you don't need a particular package version, so I'm not sure why you are specifying it in your apt commands. You're asking apt to install versions of software that aren't the ones maintained by the distro and requires dependencies that are similarly unsupported.  Try `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install mysql-client mysql-server`

Comment: Thanks everyone, But I have started reinstalling. I only ever installed mysql using sudo apt-get install mysql-server, but since upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 I had issues with that.